# Listening for login events in JBoss AS 6

Tags: java, session, authentication, jboss, jboss6.x

I have an application running in JBoss AS6. Authentication is working using the "FORM" auth method, and the user is logging in correctly.

I would like to be able to call a piece of custom, static code whenever a user successfully logs in.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any listener, or hook, or callback, which will execute code on successful login. The HttpSessionListener does have an event for "sessionCreated", but this is called as soon as a user accesses any page, even if they have not successfully logged in. That means that even *viewing* the login form triggers the event.

Could anyone point me to some documentation for JBoss AS 6 (or equivalent) which shows how to run custom code at the point when a user first successfully logs in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring `acegi` provides hooks and events for successful logins and logouts, but not sure a straight forward solution with plain `JAAS` apart from workarounds. If you can switch to spring's acegi, it would be easier.

Comment: @Rp- Unfortunately, there's no Spring in this application stack, and given that Spring and JBoss EJB tend not to play together very well I'd prefer not to go down that path...

Comment: The workaround I can think off is having a `CustomFormAuthenticator` which extends `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator` and register it in `/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml`. Now in Jboss AS 7 they introduced `valve` concept where you can register `CustomAuthenticator` in jboss-web.xml iteself.

Comment: @Rp- I'll give it a shot. It's not as elegant as I would have hoped JBoss would provide, but if it works, it works. Could you post it as an answer? That way if nothing else presents itself in the next couple of days I can award the bounty accordingly. :)

Comment: This looks related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124001/execute-code-when-sucessful-jaas-login-is-done. @Rp is probably on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `ServletFilter` implementation in front of secured Servlet.

At each invocation, the filter will test a boolean flag `notFirstCall` in `HttpSession`.

If the flag is not present, the request is the first one after user's login. It can invoke the specified job and then set the flag `notFirstCall` to mark the job as done for this session.

Comment: This is simple and cross-environment compatible, and most importantly it works, so I'm marking as accepted answer. It's a shame that there isn't a more elegant solution built into JBoss though.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I can think off is having a `CustomFormAuthenticator` which extends `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator`
 and register it in `/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml`.
Now in Jboss AS 7 they introduced valve concept where you can register `CustomAuthenticator` in `jboss-web.xml` iteself.

Something like..

```
public class CustomFormAuthenticator extends FormAuthenticator {
    @override
    public boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response, LoginConfig config) throws IOException {
        boolean authenticate = super.authenticate(request, response, config);
        //here you might need to keep track whether your custom/static code executed once or not,
        //just to avoid executing the same code again and again.
        if(authenticate) {
            int i = CustomSingleton.getInstnce().getExecuteCount();
            if(i <= 0) {
                //invoke custom code.
                //increment the count
                CustomSingleton.getInstnce().incrementExecuteCount();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, need to register this with `server` in `/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml`
Add following `entry` to `authenticators` section.

```
<entry>
    <key>CUSTOM-FORM</key>
    <value>full.qaulified.CustomFormAuthenticator</value>
</entry>
```

Then, in web.xml have `CUSTOM-FORM` as `auth-method`

```
<login-config>
     <auth-method>CUSTOM-FORM</auth-method>
          <form-login-config>
               <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
               <form-error-page>/login-error.html</form-error-page>
          </form-login-config>
<login-config>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I was trying to fix a slightly different problem (session fixation) with JBoss 6.1, and this was exactly what I needed. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) ?
Create an object, populate it how you like when a user successfully logs in and add it as an attribute to the user's session. So:

```
public class User implements Serializable, HttpSessionBindingListener {
private String userId;
private Timestame logonTime;
// any additional fields

@Override
public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
// this method called when this object is attached to a session
    log.debug("user " + this.userId + "bound to a session - user logged in");
// do stuff
  }
@Override
  public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
// this method called when user's session ends, value unbound, etc
    log.debug("user " + this.userId + "logged off");
// do other stuff
  }

}
```

To bind the object:

```
// you don't create this object until a user logs in
User userObject = new User();
userObject.setUserId();
userObject.setLogonTime();
// get your request object however you normally get it
HttpServletRequest request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedInUser", userObject);
```

When the attribute is set it will call the valueBound method
This can also come in handy for tracking users(save log on/off info to db, etc).

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I still need somewhere to put the second piece of code. It needs to be called when the user logs in, but I do not have such a place. You mention that I do not create the object until a user logs on - how do I determine when the user logs on? That's sort of where I was going with this question ticket.

Comment: As far as I understand, the second piece of code should be placed in a Servlet filter...

Comment: @YvesMartin - Putting it into a servlet filter would cause it to be run *every time* a resource was accessed, not just the first time after successful login... Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: do you have access to the JAAS modules?

Comment: @gebuh, I don't entirely understand the question. I do have configuration access to the JAAS policies.

Comment: In fact an alternate option is to create a LoginModule to receive authentication events... But as it runs in JBoss context, you cannot "do" much in the application context.

Comment: that's what I was thinking Yves, adding a custom loginModule, but I didn't realize it was in the server context.